# What is the recommended way of adding a status bar to a JavaFX app?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Should I use the `BorderPane` layout and add a label at the bottom?

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think using `BorderPane` is a good solution. You can add an `HBox` at the bottom. And in that add Labels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a VBox for my usecase. But the BorderPane can work equally well - depends on your usecase. If others have better suggestions feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 6):

It depends a bit on what you want to do with it but the ControlsFX package has a dedicated StatusBar. May be it is worth having a look at it.

[https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/tree/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/tree/master)

Comment: The old repository is no longer available.  The ControlsFX repository is available on github.